# python list comprehension without in

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

if ***flattend*** is just a list of strings, for example

```
['There','is','only','passion','and','piece','is','a','lie','lie','lie']
```

then in following two lines

```
c = Counter(flattened)
vocab = [x for x, count in c.items() if count>=2]
```

what does the part [x for x,...] mean? also, shouldn't ***count*** be of type tuple as i suppose it is a counter item? how come this part `count>=2` work?!

Note:
I understand from debugging that the first line converts the list into a counter and the second one removes the items that occurred less than twice. but i can't really interpret the syntax

Comment: I feel like this is just largely just asking for an [Explanation of List Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559625/explanation-of-list-comprehensions) and [Tuple unpacking in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867882/364696) . Not sure if there is a more complete single duplicate though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the syntax here is a little confusing, but what's actually happening is that each item in `c.items()` is a tuple containing a word and its count.

A more clear way of writing this would be:

```
vocab = [x for (x, count) in c.items() if x>=2]
```

but it could be also be done like this:

```
vocab = [x[0] for x in c.items() if x[1]>=2]
```

where `x` is a tuple.

It can also be helpful to look at what `c` actually looks like. If you print c, you see:

```
>>> print c
Counter({'lie': 3, 'is': 2, 'and': 1, 'a': 1, 'There': 1, 'only': 1, 'passion': 1, 'piece': 1})
```

and `c.items()`

```
>>> print c.items()
[('and', 1), ('a', 1), ('lie', 3), ('is', 2), ('There', 1), ('only', 1), ('passion', 1), ('piece', 1)]
```

Comment: In other words, this is equivalent of `[x for (x, count)...]`.

Comment: yeah, added the more clear unpacking syntax for clarity

Comment: @bereal: It's not just equivalent, it's identical; the defining attribute of all non-empty `tuple`s is the presence of a comma, not the parentheses; parentheses are only needed when there would be ambiguity (e.g. with function call parentheses) or precedence issues (including `tuple`s inside other collection literals). When it's not really about making `tuple`s (e.g. multiple returns, unpacking values), it's considered more Pythonic to *not* include the parentheses when they're not necessary.

Comment: @ShadowRanger in certain way, the words "equivalent" and "identical" are equivalent (or identical).

Answer (score 2):

Counter will return a dictionary like structure. So you need to iterate over keys and values, key is x and value is count. If we look closely at `c.items()`

```
c.items() #list of tuples with (key,value)

[('and', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('lie', 3),
 ('is', 2), # x->'is' ,count->2
 ('There', 1),
 ('only', 1),
 ('passion', 1),
 ('piece', 1)]
```

So if you are iterating this list for a single tuple there are two components: a word and associated count. For count you are checking if the `count>=2` if yes then returning that key which in list comphrension is x

Comment: The display you provide is only the case on Python 2; `Counter` isn't just "dictionary-like", it's a `dict` subclass, and on Python 3, that means `.items()` returns a `dict` view (a live view of the underlying `dict` with fixed overhead no matter the underlying `dict`'s size, which changes with the `dict`), not a `list` (which on Py2 is an eager copy of the key/value pairs and doesn't subsequently change with the `dict` is was generated from). As it happens, they both iterate the same (assuming the `dict` isn't mutated mid-iteration), you just won't see a `list` without wrapping in `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

`[x for x, ...]` is just using `x` as an variable while iterating over some array...

`x, count` captures the two items that serve as iterated values from `c.items()`.

If you were to print the results of: `for _ in c.items(): print(_)` That would print out a list of tuples like `(x, count)`.

`[x for x, count in c.items() if count > 2]` just preserves `x` in the array while using the `count` iterable as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down into lines:

```
vocab = [           # line0
         x          # line1
         for        # line2
         x, count   # line3
         in
         c.items()
         if
         count>=2]  # line7
```

Each `tuple` from `c.items()` is composed of a key, `x`, (the thing that was counted) and a `count` (the number of times that key was seen).

On each loop, you can imagine the next `tuple` is pulled, then unpacked, so that instead of needing to use a single value with indices `0` and `1`, you can just refer to them by name; `anontuple[0]` becomes `x`, `anontuple[1]` becomes `count`.

The `count>=2` line then filters the results; if `count` is less than `2`, we stop processing this item, and pull the next one.

The plain `x` on the far left is the item to produce; when the filtering check is passed, we shove the corresponding `x` into the resulting `list` unmodified.

Converting to a regular loop, it would look like this (lines matched to listcomp lines):

```
vocab = []                  # line0
for x, count in c.items():  # lines 2-5
    if count >= 2:          # lines 6-7
        vocab.append(x)     # line1
```

If unpacking is confusing to you, you could instead imagine it as:

```
vocab = []              # line0
for item in c.items():  # lines 2, 4 and 5
    x = item[0]         # line3
    count = item[1]     # line3
    if count >= 2:      # line 6-7
        vocab.append(x) # line1
```